# Ninja form -Constant Contact WP Plugin

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms, constantcontact

Is it possible to add more than one constant contact list for a single ninja form-contact form?

I have added a checkbox to constant contact section as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image]

the check box get unchecked after publishing the form.